# VFP generates a Word document and attach it to the record

Tags: visualforce

I'm working on a VisualForce Page that generates a Word document via HTML.
It works juste fine, but the next step is to attach the Word to the record.

I know that i have to create a new Attachment, but i dont know how to "take" all the HTML code and put in the Attachment's body.

I'm stuck with something like that :

```
Attachment attach = new Attachment(parentid = recordid, name = "Word Document", body = ?????);
insert attach;
```

Thanks for your help and have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably the [`getContent()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_getContent.htm) method on `PageReference`. You'd do something like

```
PageReference pg = Page.MyVisualforcePage;

Attachment attach = new Attachment(
    ParentId = recordid, 
    Name = 'Word Document', 
    Body = pg.getContent()
);
insert attach;
```

Important to note: `getContent()` counts as a callout, and can't be used in locations like triggers where callouts are not permitted. It also cannot be invoked in test context, and therefore may need to be gated with `Test.isRunningTest()`.